# Get substring from a fact

Tags: prolog

So I've got facts that are written like this `document(Title,Topic)`. I want to make a rule where with two arguments.The first one is Keys which is a list of keywords and the second one is the document.
 I want to get as a result the titles of the documents which cointain the keywords I've given.
This is what I wrote till now:

```
isInDoc([],'no'). %Recursion stops here. Don't know what to put as 2nd argument
isInDoc([H|T],document(Title,_)) :-
    sub_string(case_insensitive,H,document(Title,_)),
    isInDoc(T,document(Title,_)).
```

What I've thought is that I read the head of the list of keywords and see if it is a substring of the title of the document. When I type `document(Title,_)` in SWI-Prolog I get the titles of the documents. I can't think of any other way to get access to the title of the document. If I do a question I get this error `ERROR: table: sub_string/3: Type error:'text' expected, found document(_G6503,_G6504)`.
Isn't `document(Title,_)` of type text?

Comment: Are you looking for documents that each contain all the keywords? Or documents that each contain at least one keyword? And you base case should probably be, `isInDoc([], _).` (you don't care what the second argument is). And, when you say, ...*I do a question*, what does that look like?

Comment: @captain, give a sample of `document(Title,Topic)` facts.

Comment: @lurker I'm looking for documents who have at least one of the keywords. A question could be `isInDoc(['harry potter','harry','potter'],document(Title,_)).` I realize that maybe the second argument in my question might not be expressed right.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski `document('Rules and Uncertainty',
 ['Languages for the formalization of uncertainty rules',
  'Probabilistic; fuzzy and other rule frameworks for reasoning with uncertain or incomplete information']).` First argument is the title of the book, the second is a description of the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in SWI-Prolog, [sub_string](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_string/5)/5 has been introduced recently, but works only on *strings*. The correct predicate to use is [sub_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_atom/5)/5 (it is also ISO standard):

```
isInDoc(Tokens, document(Title, _)) :-
   member(Token, Tokens),
   sub_atom(Title, _,_,_, Token).

4 ?- document(T,_), isInDoc([and], document(T,_)).
T = 'Rules and Uncertainty' ;
false.

5 ?- document(T,_), isInDoc([and, certa], document(T,_)).
T = 'Rules and Uncertainty' ;
T = 'Rules and Uncertainty' ;
false.
```

I use [member](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2)/2 to 'try' all tokens, instead of writing a recursive rule. Btw, since you expect that isInDoc/2 will *fail* when any of the tokens cannot be found, you can drop altogether the base case (but since you used `no`, that will never match document(_, _), the effect is the same).

*edit* Maybe the snippet can be made more useful separating the matching of atoms from the document:

```
isInDoc(Tokens, document(Title, _)) :- contains(Tokens, Title).

contains(Tokens, Atom) :-
   member(Token, Tokens),
   sub_atom(Atom, _,_,_, Token).
```

Comment: Does is work at your pc? Because I copy pasted your code and whenever I run a question I get this message: ERROR: sub_atom/5: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.

Comment: yes, it works here, those are actual queries I issued after I saved your `document('Rules and Uncertainty', etc)`. Maybe you have `document(_,'some text')` in your fact base ?

Comment: No, I don't have anything like this in my database. I'm using SWI-prolog.

Comment: sub_atom/5 it's very permissive regarding instantiation of arguments. I think it works with the *first* and *any* combination of other 4s... try updating your question, adding the *actual* query and the error...

Comment: Now I got what I wanted. Instead of asking `document(T,_), isInDoc([and], document(T,_)).` I asked `isInDoc([and], document(T,_)).` which gave me the instantiation error. Why do I really need the fist part of the question in order for the questio to work? Can't the 2nd argument of the isInDoc read the title of the document?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Now I have to to the same but show the documents which have at least one keyword in the Title or the Topic. I'll try to figure it out. I can't be that difficult.

Comment: Yes, I think you was just missing the hint on sub_atom/5. See also once/1 in documentation if you have problems with multiple ( unwanted ) solutions.